# WordPress Insert MySQL conversion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been working on a simple website heatmap using jQuery & PHP. I've managed to make it work but I would now like to use it in WordPress and I was woundering how to covert the Insert MYSQL function to work with WordPress. See example below:

```
global $wpdb;

//$clicks = $_POST["clicks"];
$clicks = '.testimonial;1119;316;1663;608;#header;723;66;1663;608';
$keys = array('identifier_name', 'pos_x', 'pos_y','window_width','window_height');

$arr = explode(';', $clicks);
$data = array_chunk($arr, 5);

//Create an array of values for the insert statement
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rec) {
    $values[] = "(1, '" . join("', '", $rec) . "', 'ok')";
}

//Create a single insert statement with all the values
//I am trying to convert this Insert Function
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (user_id, " . join(', ', $keys) . ", status)";
$sql .= "VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);
echo $sql . '<br>';
```

I am struggeling with the array bit here:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                /* This is where I struggle */
            )
        );
```

Any help much appreceated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $rec) {
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table, 
        array( 
            'identifier_name'=> $rec[0],
            'pos_x'=>$rec[1],
            'pos_y'=>$rec[2],
            'window_width'=>$rec[3],
            'window_height'=>$rec[4])
    );
}
```

or

```
$wpdb->query($sql);
```